# Trouble with git pull

Tags: git, version-control

I'm having trouble using git.

I branched a repo and wrote some code.

My friend cloned that, made some changes, and `push --all` to the server.

I now want to see those changes with `pull`, but I'm getting the following message:

```
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.branchName.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:

    [branch "threshold"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335343/how-to-tell-git-to-always-pull-the-master-branch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell Git to always pull the master branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335343/how-to-tell-git-to-always-pull-the-master-branch)